# Kendo MVC Grid set / change edit template at runtime

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a Kendo MVC Grid

```html
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<...>()
       ....
       .Editable(ed => ed.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp).TemplateName("Editor_Name_A").Window(w => { w.Title(""); w.Width(700); }).DisplayDeleteConfirmation(false))
       .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
       ...
```

I have another two simple buttons: `button_A` and `button_B` somewhere else in the document, and what I am trying to do is, when user click `button_A`, the grid will use template `Editor_Name_A`, while if user click `button_B`, the grid will use template `Editor_Name_B`

It is like dynamically setting / changing the grid edit template conditionally, is there any way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have to do it with some javascript in the page itself and try these approaches:

1. change the template name with javascript upon clicking the buttons and reload the grid.
2. Set a global parameter, or hidden field value according to buttons click and use one template with condition inside it, that renders different html by that parameter. [check this](http://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-run-a-function-inside-a-template)

Comment: For method 1, as I am using Kendo MVC, how can I access the template name in javascript? The closest field I can find is grid.options.editable.template, which store an already rendered html string from the template, but not the template name / directory. For method 2, my template is written in .cshtml file, with a lot of razor codes inside, how can I apply kendo template in such case? Thanks!